# Typescript function return type null if parameter null

Tags: typescript, function, types

I want to let Typescript know that if the dbUser parameter passed to the function is not null, then that the result will not be null for sure.

```
type GetUser = (dbUser: DbUser | null) => GqlUser | null; 
const getUser: GetUser = (dbUser) => {
  if(!dbUser) return null;
  return ... //gql user
};

const dbUser = { ... some fields} //not null for sure
getUser(dbUser) //here I want typescript to know that the result will not be null
```

Basically, I know for sure that if dbUser parameter is not null, the result won't be either. How can I define the function in such a way?
Currently, when I call the getUser function with non-null parameter, it still says that the result could be null, which I know for sure can't.

Comment: Hi! is it possible to you to use boolean values?
(like using true or false).

For me I prefer to avoid handling null values.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There are several options. You can use a function declaration with overloads:

```
function getUser(dbUser: null) : null;
function getUser(dbUser: DbUser) : GqlUser;
function getUser(dbUser: DbUser | null) : GqlUser | null;
function getUser(dbUser: DbUser | null): GqlUser | null {
    if(!dbUser) return null;
    return null! //gql user
} 

const dbUser =  null! as DbUser
getUser(dbUser) // GqlUser
```

You can also get overloads with the arrow function and type style but they look uglier:

```
type GetUser = {
    (dbUser: null) : null;
    (dbUser: DbUser) : GqlUser;
    (dbUser: DbUser | null) : GqlUser | null;
} 
const getUser = ((dbUser: DbUser | null): GqlUser | null => {
   if(!dbUser) return null;
   return null! //gql user
}) as GetUser 

const dbUser =  null! as DbUser
getUser(dbUser)
```

You could also use conditional types:

```
type GetUser = <T extends DbUser | null>(dbUser: T) => T extends DbUser ? GqlUser : null;
const getUser: GetUser = (dbUser) => {
    if (!dbUser) return null;
    return {} as any // assertions will be required to get a value into the conditioanl type 
};

const dbUser = null! as DbUser //not null for sure
getUser(dbUser)
```

I would recommend the first option, it's the cleanest and requires not type assertions unlike the other two.

Comment: Is there a way to export and import the function declarations from a separate file? I picked the 1st solution because it avoids  the type assertions but a single file that used to be 200 lines, is going to become 500+ if not way more because now the declarations must stay before the functions.

Comment: @ZenVentzi don't think there is a way, expect for writing your code in js and using a d.ts ...

Comment: In the first example the third overload matches exactly the main function itself! why can't we avoid repetition here?

Comment: It's a great answer, but I don't think TS offers a satisfactory solution right now. For all three examples, the implementation function is not checked for the correct return types, and you can return null or string for any inputs.