# Typescript function overloads too big files

Tags: typescript, function, overloading

Is there a way to import/export function overloads or some other tactic for reducing the noise in the file with the actual functions? E.g. a file with around 250 lines of code that is bound to become 500+ if I keep the overloads in the same file.

Currently interface and type functions are not an option since they [require casting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54554036/4132182) when used for overloading purposes

Answer (score 0):

Use interfaces and arrow functions

```
// a.ts
export interface Foo {
  // overloads here...
  (a: string): string
  (): any
}

// b.ts
import {Foo} from './a'

const foo: Foo = (...args: any[]) => ...

foo()
```

P.S. You **cannot** do it with classic functions, because in that case function overloads must be placed just before the implementation.

Comment: Interfaces and types require casting(type assertion). [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54554036/4132182). So, I'm using overloads with the function keyword.

Comment: @ZenVentzi Your point is not clear. What's wrong with using a variable instead of a function? in the end you use it the same way `foo()`. And no, there is no single casting or type assertion in my answer.

Comment: There is nothing "wrong" in using variable, you're missing the point. "Interfaces and types require casting(type assertion)". That's what I am trying to avoid. And again there is nothing "wrong" in that either.

Comment: @ZenVentzi I am saying again, there is *no* casting or type assertion. Type assertion is this: `123 as 123` or `{} as any`. What you are seeing is just setting a type of a variable `foo`. What's wrong with that? Why are you trying to avoid it?

Comment: Please check the code in the link above. With interfaces/types you can't achieve what the issue is there without casting. Your function is too simplistic, not even finished